# Find $\omega$ to minimize $|X_1|^2$ using matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

**Question:** Is there an analytic way to get $\omega$ to minimize the value of $|X_1(\omega)|^2$? I tried to do it by derivating the expression setting it to zero, but I got a polynomial of order $5$ which is very hard to solve. Is there an easy way to do it, like manipulating the matrix, changing the bases and so on?

I have $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix $[M]$, $[C]$ and $[K]$ with positive constants $m_1$, $m_2$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $k_1$ and $k_2$.
$$
[M] = \begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & 0\\
0 & m_2
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [C] = \begin{bmatrix}
c_1+c_2 & -c_2\\
-c_2 & c_2
\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [K] = \begin{bmatrix}
k_1+k_2 & -k_2\\
-k_2 & k_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\underbrace{\left(\left[K \right] +i\omega [C] -\omega^2 [M]\right)}_{[A(\omega)]} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\ X_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Solving for $X_1$ we get

$$
X_1(\omega) = \dfrac{k_2+i\omega c_2-\omega^2 m_2}{D(\omega)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
D(\omega) = \det \ [A(\omega)]
$$

$$
|X_1(\omega)|^2 = \dfrac{(k_2-m_2\omega^2)^2+c_2^2 \omega^2}{D(\omega) \cdot \overline{D(\omega)}}
$$

Then I want to find $\omega$ to minimize the value of $|X_1|^2 = X_1 \cdot \overline{X_1}$.
To do it, I thought about derivate this expression and find its roots.
But it's though cause $D$ is a $\omega^4$ polynomial and when I derivate this expression, I get a polynomial like

$$\dfrac{d}{d\omega} |X_1|^2 = -4\omega m_1^2m_2^4 \cdot \dfrac{f_0 + f_1 y + f_2 y^2 + f_3 y^3 + f_4 y^4 + y^5}{\left(D(\omega) \cdot \overline{D(\omega)}\right)^2}$$

With very long expressions $f_0$, $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $f_4$, and $y=\omega^2$.
But it's very hard to find the analytic roots.

**Motivation:** I have a mass-spring-damper system with mass $m_1$, spring $k_1$ and damper $c_1$ which vibrates with an amplitude $X_1$. Then I want to couple another mass-spring-damper with constants $m_2$, $c_2$ and $k_2$ to absorb the vibrations of $X_1$ at a given frequency $\omega_{operation}$.
It's known as add a DVA (dynamic vibration absorber), like [shown here](https://youtu.be/7T6pQnNBph0).

Then, if I have a function $\omega = g(m_1, \ m_2, \ c_1, \ c_2, \ k_1, \ k_2)$, I can get the values of $k_2$, $c_2$ and $m_2$ such $\omega = \omega_{operation}$.
One obvious solution when $c_2 = 0$ is

$$
\omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{k_2}{m_2}}
$$

**PS:** $\omega = 0$ is one of the roots, but it's not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left[A\right] \cdot \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\overline{X_1} & \overline{X_2} \end{bmatrix} \cdot \left[\overline{A}\right]^{T}
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (2)
$$

Then multiplying $(1)$ by $(2)$

$$
\left[A\right] \cdot \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}X_1\overline{X_1} & X_1 \overline{X_2} \\ \overline{X_1}X_2 & X_2 \overline{X_2} \end{bmatrix}}_{[XX]}
\cdot \left[\overline{A}\right]^{T}
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (3)
$$
$$
\left[XX\right]
= \left[A\right]^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (4)
$$

Derivate $(3)$ with respect to $\omega$

$$
\left[\dfrac{dA}{d\omega}\right] \cdot [XX]
\cdot \left[\overline{A}\right]^{T} + \left[A\right] \cdot \left[\dfrac{d}{d\omega}XX\right]
\cdot \left[\overline{A}\right]^{T} + \left[\overline{A}\right] \cdot [XX]
\cdot \left[\dfrac{d\overline{A}}{d\omega}\right]^{T}
= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\left[A^{-1}\right]\left[\dfrac{dA}{d\omega}\right] \cdot [XX] +\left[\dfrac{d}{d\omega}XX\right] + [XX]
\cdot \left[\dfrac{d\overline{A}}{d\omega}\right]^{T}  \left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T}
= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

As we want only $d(X_1\overline{X}_1)/d\omega$ and it's equal zero, we multiply the sides by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \left[A^{-1}\right]\left[\dfrac{dA}{d\omega}\right] \cdot [XX] \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +\underbrace{\dfrac{d}{d\omega}X_1\overline{X}_1}_{0} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} [XX]
\cdot \left[\dfrac{d\overline{A}}{d\omega}\right]^{T}  \left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
= 0
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \left( \left[A^{-1}\right]\left[\dfrac{dA}{d\omega}\right] \cdot [XX] + [XX]
\cdot \left[\dfrac{d\overline{A}}{d\omega}\right]^{T}  \left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T}\right) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
= 0
$$

Using the equation $(4)$ I get

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \left[A^{-1}\right]}_{[F]} \left( \underbrace{\left[\dfrac{dA}{d\omega}\right] \left[A\right]^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{[B]} + \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T}
\cdot \left[\dfrac{d\overline{A}}{d\omega}\right]^{T}}_{[\overline{B}]^{T}}  \right)  \underbrace{\left[\overline{A}\right]^{-T}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} }_{[F]^{T}}
= 0
$$
$$
\left[F\right]\left[G\right]  \left[\overline{F}\right]^{T}
= 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)
$$

Now, as we know $[K]$, $[C]$ and $[M]$, then we can compute $[V]$ and $[G]$:

$$
[G] = [B] + \left[\overline{B}\right]^{T} = \dfrac{\omega}{D} \begin{bmatrix}
2g_{11} & g_{12} \\
\overline{g_{12}} & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
[V] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{D} \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}
$$

With
$$
v_1=k_2+i\omega c_2-\omega^2m_2
$$
$$
v_2=k_2+i\omega c_2
$$
$$
g_{11} = 2m_1m_2\omega^2-c_1c_2-2k_2m_1
$$
$$
g_{12} = i\omega m_2c_2 - 2m_2k_2
$$

Therefore, $(5)$ becomes

$$
\dfrac{1}{D} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \dfrac{\omega}{D} \begin{bmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ \overline{g_{12}}& 0\end{bmatrix} \cdot \dfrac{1}{D} \begin{bmatrix} \overline{v_1} \\ \overline{v_2} \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$
$$
\boxed{v_1 \overline{v_1}g_{11}+\Re\left(v_1 \overline{v_2} g_{12}\right)=0 } \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (6)
$$

Expanding $(6)$, we get

$$
v_1 \overline{v_1}g_{11} = -\left(2m_1\left(k_2-m_2\omega^2\right)+c_1c_2\right)\left(\omega^2c_2^2+\left(k_2-\omega^2 m_2\right)^2\right)
$$
$$
\Re\left(v_1 \overline{v_2} g_{12}\right)  = -m_2\left[c_2^2 \omega^2\left(2k_2-\omega^2m_2\right)+2k_2^2\left(k_2-\omega^2m_2\right)\right]
$$

Which is a polynomial of order $6$, but only with terms $\omega^2$, $\omega^4$ and $\omega^6$.

For the case $c_2$ this equations becomes

$$
\left(k_2 -m_2\omega^2\right) \left[\left(k_2-m_2w^2\right)^2 + \dfrac{m_2}{m_1}\cdot k_2^2 \right] = 0$$